# MongoDB designing issue

Tags: mongodb

I want to create an array of ratings, and inside this array I want somehow associate rating and date this rating was checked.
right now I have this solution:

```
> db.foo.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("511a604f546e6b3019d5e673"),
    "ratings" : [
        {
            "rating" : 3,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-02-12T15:31:27.950Z")
        },
        {
            "rating" : 5,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-02-12T15:34:12.072Z")
        },
        {
            "rating" : 3,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-02-12T15:34:33.009Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

With this "schema" I see the only one BIG issue, I think it's little to complicated to sort documents by date, if I'm wrong, please correct me. How would you design it?

Comment: Why not have a separate "ratings" collection whose documents also have a reference to the "foo" document to which they belong?

Comment: Because I concern about performance, and want to use NoSQL advantages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Store the ratings in a separate "ratings" collection.

This strategy adds the minor complication of needing two queries to display a "foo" and its ratings (one query for each collection) but has the advantage of flexibility and scalability.

See also this advice from 10gen: [Storing Comments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/#storing-comments).

Comment: You right, this way it will be very easy to sort it. One of the things I was concern about, I wanted to store as much as possible in one document, and not to create to many tables